# Cannot bring output rows of sql server into php using sqlsrv

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqlsrv

Please note that i tried all existing solutions and still haven't got output.

I have a php page that calls a Stored Procedure in SQL Server using sqlsrv functions. I have tried existing solutions but unable to solve my problem. When i execute this same SP in SQL Management Studio, it gives output of 31 rows. However, here in my code i am unable to get any row of data. Could someone advise on how to?
Here is my code:

```
$serverName = "(local)"; //serverName\instanceName
// Server in the this format: <computer>\<instance name> or 
// <server>,<port> when using a non default port number
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"TESTDB");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
   $AcCode = '18100017';
   $StartDate = '2016/12/01';
   $EndDate = '2016/12/31';
   $CutAmt = -50000;
   $IntRate1 = 2;
   $IntRate2 = 3;

   $sql = "EXEC dbo.uspGetBankInterest @AC_NO= ?, @AsOfDate= ?, @EndDate= ? ,@CutAmt= ?, @IntRate1= ?, @IntRate2= ?";
    $stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $sql, array(&$AcCode,&$StartDate,&$EndDate,&$CutAmt,&$IntRate1,&$IntRate2));
    $result=sqlsrv_execute($stmt);
    if( !$stmt ) {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }

    if($result){
        echo "SP Executed!";
    }

   $ctr=0;
    $row_count = sqlsrv_num_rows( $stmt );
    echo ' '.$row_count.'<br>';
    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            print_r($stmt);
            echo($row['STAT_DATE'].' '.$row['STAT_AMT'].' '.$row['INT_AMT']."<br>");
            $ctr++; 
        }
        echo 'The total number of records are:'.$ctr;

    die();
}

else{
 echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
 die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

The output i get is:

> SP Executed! 
>   The total number of records are:0

When i executed, there was an output of 31 records and the data was displayed correctly. There is no problem in my SP. However, when i am trying it in php, no data is brought. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: `$result` return only boolean value. It doesn't return any resource. I just check if it is true or not.

Comment: As I recall you get the sql query results one way for a query and have to bring the data in differently if you call a stored procedure.  I suggest you search for examples online that specifically are for stored procedures if you have never done a stored procedure result set with the technology stack you are using.  You may even try a basic stored proc that selects data with no parameters to make trouble shooting easier.  Get that to work first.  Not properly sending parameters can cause an issue too.